# Concatenating Eigen Tensors

Tags: eigen, tensor

I am working with tensors in Eigen and need to join two tensors together to form a higher order tensor. As an example:

C_ijkl = A_ik B_jl

I know I can do this with some for loops but is there a better way?

Edit:
Following the answer below I implemented this into code. Using the g++ compiler with -O3 and comparing an explicit loop versus the contraction shown below I got the following results for 10,000 iterations:

```
Average time (ns) for explicit loop: 196.782
Average time (ns) for contraction  : 790.439
```

So it seems like with my test setup a naive explicit loop is faster (though messier) than a contraction.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

#include<chrono>
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;

using namespace Eigen;

int main() {

//Initialize
Tensor<double, 2> A_ij(4, 4);
Tensor<double, 2> B_kl(4, 4);
Tensor<double, 4> C_ijkl(4, 4, 4, 4);

A_ij.setValues({{ 1, 2, 3, 4},
                { 5, 6, 7, 8},
                { 9,10,11,12},
                {13,14,15,16}});

B_kl.setValues({{17,18,19,20},
                {21,22,23,24},
                {25,26,27,28},
                {29,30,31,32}});

Tensor<double, 4> Ctrue_ijkl(4, 4, 4, 4);

int nrepeat = 10000;
double avg_time_explicit;
double avg_time_contract;

auto t1 = Clock::now();
auto t2 = Clock::now();

array<Eigen::IndexPair<long>,0> empty_index_list = {};

for (int r=0; r<nrepeat; r++){
    t1 = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
            for (int k=0; k<4; k++){
                for (int l=0; l<4; l++){
                    Ctrue_ijkl(i,j,k,l) = A_ij(i,j)*B_kl(k,l);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    t2 = Clock::now();
    avg_time_explicit += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2-t1).count()/static_cast<double>(nrepeat);
}



for (int r=0; r<nrepeat; r++){
    t1 = Clock::now();
    C_ijkl = A_ij.contract(B_kl, empty_index_list);
    t2 = Clock::now();
    avg_time_contract += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2-t1).count()/static_cast<double>(nrepeat);
}

//Check to make sure the two methods produce the same result
Map<VectorXd> mt(C_ijkl.data(), C_ijkl.size());
Map<VectorXd> mr(Ctrue_ijkl.data(), Ctrue_ijkl.size());

std::cout << "Ctrue_ijkl == C_ijkl: " << mt.isApprox(mr) << "\n";

std::cout << "Average time (ns) for explicit loop: " << avg_time_explicit << "\n";
std::cout << "Average time (ns) for contraction:   " << avg_time_contract << "\n";

}
```

Comment: Did you compile with the `NDEBUG` compiler flag to turn off Eigen's run-time assertions in that comparison? Otherwise that could cause the time difference.

Comment: @DavidAce I didn't originally but the results are a mixed bag. I tried two things: `g++ -std=gnu+11 -DNDEBUG ...` which gave better performance for the concatenation and `g++ -std=gnu+11 -DNDEBUG -O3 ...` which gave better performance for the explicit loop.

Comment: I think your title is inappropriate. The operation you want to perform is the outer product and not concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question is the same as:  [How do I do outer product of tensors in Eigen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40829887/6248145), where I also answered with the following:

> You have to *contract over no indices*.
>
> ```cxx
> Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<long>,0> empty_index_list = {};
> Tensor<double, 2> A_ij(4, 4);
> Tensor<double, 2> B_kl(4, 4);
> Tensor<double, 4> C_ijkl = A_ij.contract(B_kl, empty_index_list);
> ```

Comment: That does the trick! It seems to be very inefficient though (see original post).